# Python Selenium- trying to get text in an object that has no text variable and random class name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the last message written on Discord's website but this is the HTML:[image: enter image description here:]

I can't just copy the class's name because it doesn't have any order(I don't want to get that specific message, the class name changes with everyone)

I can get the main element by xpath using "role" but I don't know how to get the correct class inside of it or the text inside that class.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Paste this html code into the question

Comment: Where are your code attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely get it be incorporating `re` module. Try out something like this:

`msgs_list = find_elements_by_class_name(re.compile(r'message-.+'))`

So, it will look for classes that contain `message-` and at least some random id. You'll have to test it, maybe clean it up a bit.

Note, you'll need to `import re`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'messageContent')]
```

Or

```
//div[contains(@class,'messageContent') and contains(@class,'markup')]
```

To see the text output, assign it to a variable:

```
el_text= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'messageContent') and contains(@class,'markup')]").text
print(el_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

So from what I understand, this is what you want:

1. Locate that highlighted element successfully:

   ```
   element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(`div[role="listitem"]')
   ```
2. get class from element

   ```
   class_text = element.get_attribute('class')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'contents')/h2/div").text
```